# Changing the colour of a box to royal purple?

Tags: box

I'm quite new to overleaf, im looking to change a box to the color of `royalpurple`, the shade of `Loughborough university's logo` as the header color and a lighter version as the boxes background. Any values I edit turns the colors black or a color that doesn't represent the color I input. Can someone show me how its done please? I cant find any tutorials that work, unless I'm missing something.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{colback=RoyalPurple!5!white,
colframe=RoyalPurple!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=Royapurple!85!black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1} 
\begin{mybox}[colback=purpl]{Hello there}
This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Use `\documentclass[12pt,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{colback=RoyalPurple!5!white,
colframe=RoyalPurple!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=RoyalPurple!85!black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1} 
\begin{mybox}[colback=purple]{Hello there}
This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Thankyou so much! you dont know how much i appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I will be happy to delete this since it is really just correcting a number of typos and omissions.

1. In order to use `RoyalPurple`, you need to make sure that `xcolor` is loaded with the `dvipsnames` option. One way of achieving this is to add `dvipsnames` to the options of `\documentclass`.
2. You load `tcolorbox` twice. However, for enhanced you need the `skins` library. And loading it once is sufficient. While you do not use `listings` here, I kept it and load `\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}`.
3. There were typos in the colors. `RoyalPurple` got misspelled as `Royapurple`, and `purple` as `purpl`.

Fixing these omissions and typos yields

```
\documentclass[12pt,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{colback=RoyalPurple!5!white,
colframe=RoyalPurple!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=RoyalPurple!85!black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1} 
\begin{mybox}[colback=purple]{Hello there}
This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options.
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]